# Is SharedPreferences expected to be wiped of when Android's factory reset is performed?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm looking for storing some data in my app that needs to be wiped off when Factory reset is performed. Is SharedPreferences the right storage to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will be wiped off. Database will be wiped off as well. The only data that will persist is whatever you store on SD card

Answer (score 0):

`Android's backup service`
 allows you to copy your persistent application data to remote "cloud" storage, in order to provide a restore point for the application data and settings. If a `user performs a factory reset or converts to a new Android-powered device,` the system `automatically restores` your backup data when the application is re-installed. This way, your users don't need to reproduce their previous data or application settings.

Refer [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html), you will get the complete details